# Completely deleting duplicates words in a text file

Tags: python

I have some words in a text file like:

```
joynal
abedin
rahim
mohammad
joynal
abedin 
mohammad
kudds
```

I want to delete the duplicate names. It will delete these duplicate entries totally from the text file

The output should be like:

```
rahim 
kuddus
```

I have tried some coding but it's only giving me the duplicate values as one like `1.joynal` and `2.abedin`.

**Edited:** This is the code I tried:

```py
content = open('file.txt' , 'r').readlines()
content_set = set(content)
cleandata = open('data.txt' , 'w')

for line in content_set:
    cleandata.write(line)
```

Comment: You claim to have "tried some coding" but forgot to include it in your question.

Comment: Show the wrong code, then we elaborate on that

Comment: sorry i forgot to paste it. i just edited it now

Comment: Please don't change your question by putting the answer in it like that — it makes thing incomprehensible to others. Just accept and up-vote that answer below you like best.

Comment: i cant up vote but i selected the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter 

with open(fn) as f:
    cntr=Counter(w.strip() for w in f)
```

Then just print the words with a count of 1:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(w for w,cnt in cntr.items() if cnt==1))
rahim
kudds
```

Or do it the 'old fashion way' with a dict as a counter:

```
cntr={}
with open(fn) as f:
    for line in f:
        k=line.strip()
        cntr[k]=cntr.get(k, 0)+1

>>> print('\n'.join(w for w,cnt in cntr.items() if cnt==1))
# same
```

If you want to output to a new file:

```
with open(new_file, 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write('\n'.join(w for w,cnt in cntr.items() if cnt==1))
```

Comment: i want to save it in a text file only with unique names.

Comment: can you explain this line means: with open(fn) as f:
    cntr=Counter(w.strip() for w in f)

Comment: many many thanks to you bro...i got what i need this is the final code i got: from collections import Counter 

with open("file.txt") as f:
    cntr=Counter(w.strip() for w in f)
    
with open("final.txt", 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write('\n'.join(w for w,cnt in cntr.items() if cnt==1))

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("yourFile.txt")    # open file
text = file.read()             # returns content of the file
file.close()

wordList = text.split()        # creates list of every word 
wordList = list(dict.fromkeys(wordList))    # removes duplicate elements

str = ""
for word in wordList:     
    str += word
    str += " "           # creates a string that contains every word

file = open("yourFile.txt", "w")

file.write(str)          # writes the new string in the file
file.close()
```

Comment: is it gonna replace the old one with same name?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: the output showing like this ['joynal', 'abedin', 'jobayid', 'mohammad', 'akbar', 'rahim']
but i want to save the only unique names only also in a text file too

Comment: yeah, now it writes the words in the file.

Comment: got this error: io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: whoops, you have to add "w+" or just "w" as parameter in open(), sorry.

Comment: its entirely deleting my whole values also not saving it in the file...just completely deleting the whole values inside the text file

Comment: Haven't used python very much recently, sorry. I forgot that the content gets deleted when you call open("file", "w"). It should finally work now.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you don't care about order:

```py
with open(fn) as f:
    words = set(x.strip() for x in f)

with open(new_fn, "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(words))
```

Where `fn` is the file you want to read from, and `new_fn` the file you want to write to.

In general for uniqueness think `set`---remembering that order is not gauranteed.

Comment: on the first line can you tell me what does this mean open(fn) as f? is the fn is my file name?

Comment: See edit.  Note that this method is entirely identical to @dawg's, except that I used a set.

Answer (score 0):

you can just create a list which appends if name is not in and remove if name is in and occured a 2nd time.

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f, open("output_file.txt", "w") as g:
    output_list = []
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        if not word in output_list:
            output_list.append(word)
        else:
            output_list.remove(word)
    
    g.write("\n".join(output_list))

print(output_list)

['rahim', 'kudds']

#in the text it is for each row one name like this:

rahim
kudds
```

The solution with counter is still the more elegant way imo